# How to change default input language in TextInputEditText java Android

Tags: java, android-studio, android-edittext, locale

Help me to understand.
Java Android
My application has support from API 23 to 32.
If API 24-29 then to change the default language you need to write:

```
TextInputEditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 29) {
        editText.setImeHintLocales(new LocaleList(new Locale("ar", "SA")));
    }
```

But what to do when API 23 and > 29

If the keyboard is set to the desired language, say Arabic.
When the user clicks on the edittext, the Arabic layout should open by default. Now if you switch to Arabic and reset the cursor from the edittext, then when you click again, the English language opens (again)

Comment: You aren't forcing the user to use this languages. These are just "hints". The user can still use a keyboard with his own language.

Comment: If the desired layout is installed on the phone. After the wedge on the edittext, it is necessary that the layout that I will install appears.
Before version 29 this code worked for some reason.
If not the correct approach, then tell me exactly how I should have written it